# How to fetch number of the text?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the text like "It's the 145 of 13221 items". I need to fetch all the number("145 and 13221") of text on one time. I want to use regex to do this. What is the regex like? "\d+" is not work fine.

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: You wrote: "I need to fetch all the number of text on one time." Please clarify what you mean by this, perhaps specifying what sort of output you're looking for. The reason that you're not getting good answers is that it's hard to tell what the actual problem is that you're having.

Comment: OK. I update question now. And I working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something like `^[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*$`. Depends on what flavor of regex you are using.

This regex matches:

1. Zero or more non-numeric characters at the start ("It's the ")
2. One or more numeric characters in capture group #1 ("145")
3. Zero or more non-numeric characters (" of ")
4. One or more numeric characters in capture group #2 ("13221")
5. Zero or more non-numeric characters at the end ("items")

Comment: Yeah! I try it. It's work. Thanks a lot. I will find how it work later.I need to back to work now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`\d+` works fine. Depending on language, you may have to escape the slash to `"\\d+"`, e.g. in Java.

```
    String text = "It's the 145 of 13221 items";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    // prints "145", "13221"
```

You need to figure out how to find regex matches in a string in your language, but the pattern `\d+` will match a non-zero sequence of consecutive digits.

---

In Javascript, you can do something like this:

```
function findDigitSequences(s) {
    var re = new RegExp("\\d+", "g");
    return s.match(re);
}
```

Comment: I know "\d+". But it cann't fetch number in one time. For example, "It's the 145 of 13221 items" it will give me "145,1,14,45,4,5 and so on".

Comment: @Gord: you mean given a string `"145"`, you want to explode it to all the different substrings `"145", "1", "14", "45", "4", "5"`? That's not regex, that's just listing substrings of a string from all legal indices `i, j`.

Comment: No. I just want 145 and 13221.In java, it work fine. But I working with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\D\w]+([\d]+)[\D\w]+([\d]+).+$
```

Capture Groups:

1. 145
2. 13221

Sorry my brain was off when I wrote that